# DateTime.kind property

Tags: c#, datetime

Have a small doubt with the `DateTime.kind` property. Documentation says that `kind` property have three fields `Unspecified, Local, and Utc` to show how the datetime object is represented.

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(dt1.Kind);
```

Which shows "Local" but in some microsoft documentation I red that system date and time that Windows maintains is UTC rather than local time.

If that is the case then the above `WriteLine` should output it as UTC rather than Local?

Any idea?

--Rahul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime.Now` is meant to retrieve the current *local* time. `DateTime.UtcNow` retrieves the current UTC time.

Note that this is unrelated to how Windows itself stores the time. I believe it stores the current time in UTC, but also keeps track of the current time zone, so it can display the appropriate local time. I believe this is what `DateTime.Now` does as well.